# Codeigniter Rest API call

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

I am trying to implement REST API from [github](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)

In my existing Codeigniter project.

There is a library in which trait is defined. I am trying to use that library `"REST_Controller"`

In my controller file `"Api.php"`. But I am getting error on the line where is am using the `"use"` keyword to implement it which says that unable to

**Error**

> **"Trait 'REST_Controller' not found"

```php
class Books extends CI_Controller {    
        use REST_Controller  { 
        REST_Controller::__construct as private __resTraitConstruct;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Import the trait on top of your class in order to be able to use it

```php
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

class Books extends CI_Controller {    
        use REST_Controller  { 
        REST_Controller::__construct as private __resTraitConstruct;  
}
```